# Which *.o file or which library corresponds to symbols dumped by objdump?

Tags: c, objdump

Is there any way to know where the symbol comes from using `objdump`.

I have few symbols when i do `objdump` on my elf file (as follows):

```
8010864 g   F   .text   0000007c    __floatdisf

8010864 g   F   .text   0000007c    __aeabi_l2f

8010854 g   F   .text   0000008c    __floatundisf
```

I am not sure where they come from. They are not part of the `libm` library.

Comment: How about running `objdump` on all the object files separately?

Comment: is your elf file stripped or not?

Comment: No one keeps a dictionary of symbols.  What is the name of the object file?

Comment: @KerrekSB I tried greping the objdump of all the .o files that are used to create the elf file. But symbols don't appear anywhere in any of the object files.

Comment: @BlackFrog Yes I know that no one keeps a dictionary of symbols. That is why I am trying to find out if there is any way to know where the symbols come from using some sort of compiler tool on the elf file

Comment: @tristan Hmm I do see a -g flag in the make file. So maybe it is stripped - if that is what you are asking?

Comment: if your binary is compiled with -g and is not stripped, it should be doable to find the source file where a symbol comes from. But do you expect to find the static library file or the source file of a symbol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These functions are glue inserted by the compiler for conversions from integer to floating-point types. (`floatdisf` converts signed integer to float, `floatundisf` converts unsigned integer to float, and `aeabi_l2f` is an alias for `floatdisf`.)

The implementations of these functions in LLVM can be found at:

- https://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/compiler-rt/trunk/lib/floatdisf.c
- https://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/compiler-rt/trunk/lib/floatundisf.c

As the path suggests, they are part of the [`compiler_rt`](http://compiler-rt.llvm.org/) library, which is linked in automatically as needed.

Answer (score 0):

First of all extract all .o files from the lib.a (in some temp directory)
`ar -x lib.a`

then find which .o file contains your symbol using below command
`ar -t lib.a | xargs grep "symbol" -l`